# Google Maps Javascript v3 Polyline click event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

I'm trying to make display a map with a number of routes laid out as polylines. When a polyline is clicked I want to display data specific to that line. Associating data with a line isn't a problem, but no matter which line is clicked the data displayed is associated with the most recent line drawn, as if each new polyline overwrites the last. 
I have a database which contains a link to a gpx file, a link to a video, type of route (which indicates the colour) and some other stuff. 
The line is drawn by parsing the gpx file and pushing the google maps latlng variables into an array:

```
                          var p = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng); 
                          points.push(p);     
                    }
                    var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
                          // style here
                              path: points,
                              strokeColor: "Random Colour", //seems to save over the previous colour for each line
                              strokeOpacity: .5,
                              strokeWeight: 4
                        });
                    playVideo(poly, video, map); // Click event function.
                    poly.setMap(map);
             });
```

The click event function is basically as follows:

```
function playVideo(poly, video, map){
    google.maps.event.addListener(poly, 'click', function(h) {

             document.getElementById('play').innerHTML = '<iframe width="640" height="360"' + ' src='+ video + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
         });
}
```

I can't find any solution to this, and have been stuck for a while. It works fine using markers and binding info windows to them, but I need to be able to click on the line. Any help at all is appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo (missing `"` in the "src" of the `playVideo` function).

```
function playVideo(poly, video, map){
  google.maps.event.addListener(poly, 'click', function(h) {
         document.getElementById('play').innerHTML = '<iframe width="640" height="360"' + ' src='+ video + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
  });
}
```

Should be:

```
function playVideo(poly, video, map){
  google.maps.event.addListener(poly, 'click', function(h) {
         document.getElementById('play').innerHTML = '<iframe width="640" height="360"' + ' src="'+ video + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
  });
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hypjLtts/)

Comment: Sorry, must've just done that editing the code to stick it up here, the link to the video works. I'm just trying to figure out why each poly line can't have a different video associated with it.

Comment: Then please provide an example with more than one "video" (a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue)